# Why the error is not displayed when using formik useField?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-forms

My task is to write a code to select a date.
Here's what me have now:

```js
export let DatePicker = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  let [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props.name)
  let { value, touched, error } = meta
  if(value === null)
    value = {}
  let { setValue, setTouched, setError } = helpers
  let days = [], meses = []
  for(let i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    days.push(i)
  for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    meses.push(i)
  console.log(error)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{label}</p>
      <select>
        {days.map(day => (
          <option
            onClick={() => {
              setValue({ ...value, day })
              setTouched(true)
              if(value.day === undefined || value.mes === undefined)
                setError('Error!')
            }}
            key={day} value={day} label={day}
          />
        ))}
      </select>
      <select>
        {meses.map(mes => (
          <option
            onClick={() => {
              setValue({ ...value, mes })
              setTouched(true)
              if(value.day === undefined || value.mes === undefined)
                setError('Error!')
            }}
            key={mes} value={mes} label={mes}
          />
        ))}
      </select>
      {touched && error && (
        <div className="form_error">{error}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the console I see that "Error!" Is displayed first, then immediately undefined. I don't understand what the problem is, help who can